# Moving a player with Box2D

Tags: c++, c, box2d

What is the proper way of moving a player in Box2D setting Player->ApplyForce() kind of feels like it lacks flexibility and control. What other ways might there be to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe I am wrong but, are you not using OpenGL for graphics? Why not move it with that?

Comment: no, i'm using Allegro and Box2D

Comment: Weren't you using OpenGL before for your FPS?

Comment: I work on multiple projects :p

Comment: -1 RTFM: http://www.box2d.org/manual.html... ApplyLinearImpulse / ApplyImpulse depending on your version.

Comment: OpenGL is a display technology, not a physics simulation.  Consider OpenGL the View and the physics sim as the Controller.

Comment: @Nick I did RTFM, but ApplyImpulse is very similar to ApplyForce() which I did not like the effect of,

Comment: Milo, your question should have stated this more clearly then, as what you really meant is "set the position". "Move" is generally accepted as the ongoing process of changing position, rather than disappearing from one spot and reappearing at another. When it comes to math & physics, you want to be unambiguous with you terminology. I've returned your point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SetPosition()` could do it, but it really depends on what effect you're after.